# Why does JMeter's thread number not translate to TPS at all?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a test plan that invokes one operation with a Stepping Thread Group:
[image: Stepping Thread Group configuration]

When I run this configuration I get the following TPS graph:
[image: JMetersDefaultTPSGraph]

I can only assume that this averages TPS over a minute. Observe the max TPS at around 65.

If we look at Response Time vs Requests Per Second, we see that we had 251 requests per second.

[image: ResponseTimesVsRequestsPerSecond]

In addition, the total number of samples was 23,904 for the whole run.

I was expecting the TPS graph to show data points for each second. Why does it show *Transactions **per second*** only aggregated (without indication of what statistic was used) over a minute?

I was expecting the total sample count to be at least 500*60 = 30,000 if I only consider one minute (e.g. between seconds 20-80). Why do I have 23k in total? My service's dashboard confirms the low amount of requests (can't see TPS, but TPM which is around 2k per minute).

[image: tpm metrics from my service]

Why is the request count going down with increased threads (e.g. first 2 minutes is 500, at the end it's supposed to be 2000 threads)?

Is my following base assumption incorrect?

I assume that JMeter's thread groups (here a stepping one), starts up e.g. 500 threads. All 500 threads send a request. As most requests' response times are below 1s, I would expect at least 500 TPS. What am I missing? Looking at other SO answers, it seems like it is supposed that each thread executes all samplers as fast as possible. Is there a graph showing how long each sampler takes? I tried removing all but the necessary ones but it didn't change anything.

Side question: I use the Plugin Manager and if run JMeter via the UI additional graphs as set up by me are showing (especially a real TPS graph that has datapoints each second), but if run via CLI, I can't find those graphs in the generated html report. How do I get those included?

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any other metrics/graphs from the default html report.

Answer (score 0):

> I can only assume that this averages TPS over a minute.

You are very smart and nailed it:

[image]

The "granularity" is controllable via `jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity` JMeter property so you can consider amending the default value of 60000 ms to something lower, i.e. 5 seconds.

You can re-generate the reporting dashboard out of the existing .jtl file as follows:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=5000 -g /path/to/result.jtl -o /path/to/dashboard
```

If you want the change to be permanent - put the `jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=5000` line to *user.properties* file.

In general if the number of transaction per second isn't in line with the throughput it means that either JMeter cannot run requests fast enough or your application cannot process them fast enough so in any case it needs to be analyzed.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Reporting configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)
- [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second)